# Any way to make a trigger or button to let user push and RUN, instead of going to Script Editor?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have made some functions in my script editor, but while I need my spreadsheet go live every time, I need to go to script editor and push Run button to let scripts run faster, otherwise it takes a few minutes to run.  I am wondering if there is any way to make a button in my sheet, or a trigger to run it every time with no need to going to script editor?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking here. Can you please provide some code and try to explain more about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is what I mean:  I have a function to search for a value in my first column and add date to the last column and move the entire row to another sheet (means copy the row to another sheet and delete it). This operation takes a few minutes every time, while I need my sheet be updated faster; now I go to script editor and push the "run" button to execute the operation faster, and it works, but I want to make the same button, in my spreadsheet to let other ordinary users push to update the sheet or execute the operation faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this following function in your appscript.

What it will do?
It will add new menu option in your spreadsheet along with 'file','view','edit' etc menus. Click that and you will have your function name shown. Click it and it will trigger your appscript.

Here's the code:

```
function onOpen() 
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Submit Sheet')
      .addItem('Generate Output', 'YOUR_FUNCTION_TO_RUN')
    .addToUi()
}
```

And, set trigger for onOpen() function as this: From spreadsheet -> on Open.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an Apps Script functin to an image or drawing in Google Sheets, such that it will run every time you click it. Select an image or drawing in Google Sheets, click the down arrow icon at the top, and select *Assign script.* More information is available in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets).